# Migrating from 2.0 to 4.5.1 causes program to look for separate resource assembly

Tags: .net

I'm in the process of migrating some software from .NET 2 to 4.5.1. The application consists of a main program and a dll (let's call it `foo.dll`). Both the main program and the dll are loaded by a loader application (through `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` and `Assembly.Load`).

After going to 4.5.1, as soon as my code touches an embedded resource, the runtime tries to load `foo.resources.dll`, which it obviously cannot find since there is no such file. This only happens if I run it through my loader. If I run it directly it works as it should.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is a change in the way `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` works in .NET 4.0. From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resolveeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) page for `ResolveEventHandler`:

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the System.ResolveEventHandler event is raised for all assemblies, including resource assemblies. In earlier versions, the event was not raised for resource assemblies. If the operating system is localized, the handler might be called multiple times: once for each culture in the fallback chain.

So what would appear to happen here is that the runtime is looking for resource/satellite assemblies, just *in case* they're there. Previously there wouldn't have been a scenario where the handler was raised for something that might not exist. Due to the change, the solution now is to simply return null instead of throwing.